# Android sqlcipher getDatabaseName()

Tags: android, sqlcipher

In my project, I'm using correctly the library https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/. Now I need to get the name of the database. In classic SQLite, there is a method getDatabaseName () instead cipher does not seem to have it, how can I do? do you have an idea?

[image]

```
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper;

    public class DbCrypt extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "data.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private static SQLiteDatabase db = null;


public DbCrypt(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    DbCrypt.db = db;
...
...
 }


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
```

**EDIT**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your subclass of SQLCipher's edition of `SQLiteOpenHelper`, implement a `getDatabaseName()` method that returns your database name. You could also use this in the constructor, so you do not have to repeat the database name value:

```
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper;

    public class DbCrypt extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "data.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private static SQLiteDatabase db = null;


public DbCrypt(Context context) {
    super(context, getDatabaseName(), null, DB_VERSION);

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    DbCrypt.db = db;
...
...
 }


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}

public String getDatabaseName() {
    return(DB_NAME);
}
```

Comment: I had already tried inserting method getDatabaseName(), but I still have the same error, the method is not invoked. See new image, I edited my post.

Comment: @user2847219: You need to change your method signature on `get()` to take a `DbCrypt` object, not a `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.